# Pre-/postprocessing of DSL edited with TMF-based editor

Tags: xtext, emf

Given:

Some kind of DSL parsed with Xtext parser and then edited by user in TMF-based editor.

When user open file for editing I want first get access to the parse tree of just opened file, modify loaded file content in a some way and then provide to user modified source for editing.

When user wish to save file I again want to preprocess text representation based on actual parse tree and save such altered version.

Is there any Xtext/EMF API  to implement such pre-/post- processing?

The goal is to add some content not presented in the physical file, allow user to edit this content and remove it before saving to file. This extra content should be stored separately from DSL source file.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display additional information in the text editor itself (and not add additional information only to the EMF model, not to the text, for which [IDerivedStateComputer](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/blob/v2.14.0/org.eclipse.xtext/src/org/eclipse/xtext/resource/IDerivedStateComputer.java) could be used).

If the user is not supposed to edit the additional text, the "Code Mining" feature might be useful: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/310_eclipse_support.html#code-mining and https://blogs.itemis.com/en/code-mining-support-in-xtext

To answer the question itself:

> Is there any Xtext/EMF API to implement such pre-/post- processing?

No, I am pretty sure there is no such Xtext API for pre-/post-processing files based on their own parse tree (EMF is irrelevant as you want to change the physical content). You could try to mess around with the XtextDocumentProvider (i.e. create your own subclass and register it in the UI module), but this is very likely to break the UI because the line numbers and offsets won't match.

You might have more luck implementing a [custom Eclipse action](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html) that is executed on the original file and creates a temporary modified copy based on the parsed original file and then opens an editor for the temporary file. Then you could implement a IXtextBuilderParticipant that writes the result back to the original file on save (you have to register it using the org.eclipse.xtext.builder.participant extension point).

Another idea would be not to use an Eclipse action but a tabbed editor using [MultiPageEditorPart](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fpart%2FMultiPageEditorPart.html), with the original as one of three tabs (the composite file and the 'additional info' file being the other two).

Comment: Additional text should be editable by user in same way as a regular text.
"Code Mining" looks interesting, but, unfortunately, they are not editable.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to add some content not presented in the physical file, allow user to edit this content and remove it before saving to file. This extra content should be stored separately from DSL source file.

Couldn't you present this information in another view similar to the 'Properties' view of EMF ? e.g. the user opens file, the Xtext editor opens as well as the 'Properties' view, which presents a way to edit these "extra" information. Upon save of either view, the Xtext save is called and your extra properties are serialized in their own model.